# Change jquery datetimepicker format on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

After much too much googling and searching stackoverflow for my answer, I have been unsuccessful. So I am sorry if this is a duplicate.

I have a datepicker that displays only time. I wish to toggle between military and standard time on a dropdown onchange event.

My attempts have been something of this:

```
function militarytoggle(element)
{
     timetype = $("#military").val();
     if(timetype == "military")
     {
         $('.time').datetimepicker({
              timeOnly: true,
              timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
         });
     }
     else if(timetype == "standard"){
         $('.time').datetimepicker({
              timeOnly: true,
              timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'
         });
     }
}
```

EDIT: The datetime method I am using (that is currently working) is rendered on document ready:

```
$('.time').datetimepicker({
timeOnly: true,
    dateFormat: '',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'
});
```

I only wish to change timeFormat on an event.

One would think this would work, redundancy aside. What on Earth am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your if statements is written as

```
if($(timetype == "military")
```

the other as

```
else if(timetype == "standard")
```

First of all, the former of those has unclosed parenthesis. But also, one uses $ and the other doesn't. Only one of these can be the correct syntax (I'm thinking the later).

Similarly, you use

```
$('.time').datepicker
```

in one place and

```
$('.time').datetimepicker
```

in the other. Again, only one of these is probably the right method to use.

Edit: added from comments below:

If the datetimepicker method is a constructor, calling it again after the page has been created may not actually change the format of an existing control.

Further:

You should check the documentation (or the source code if there is no good documentation) of the datetime picker widget to see if there is a method for changing the display format of an existing control (or if the format is a public property you might be able to assign it directly). If there is not, then having two versions initialized and hiding one is probably the best way to do it, although you could also do a post back to the server, and have some server side code that uses a passed parameter to render a page with the datetimepicker set to the desired format.

Comment: Those were typos, upvoted for the catch, unfortunately not the solution to my problem :( (thanks though!) It should be noted that I have tried every from of both of the above...

Comment: @steve In that case I would suspect the datetimepicker method doesn't actually do what you think it does. Can you link what datetimepicker exactly you're using?

Comment: @steve Not really what I meant. I don't think jQuery comes with a datetimepicker control as such, it's an add on you are getting from somewhere (jQuery UI? Bootstrap?). If that method is a constructor, calling it again after the page has been created may not actually change the format of an existing control.

Comment: again you are correct, It is part of jQuery UI. Pardon my ignorance! :( Your above comment answers the question btw. Add it to your answer and I will accept (changing after page load may not actually change the format of an existing control)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by adding a military and standard time field for each form. I then toggle the disabled property as well as the display CSS instead of trying to change the datetimepicker.

Then I just bind datetime picker to all fields on document ready.

```
function militarytoggle(element)
{
    timetype = $("#military").val(); 
    if(timetype == "military")
    {
        $(".standard").prop("disabled",true).css("display","none");
        $(".military").prop("disabled",false).css("display","block");
    }else if(timetype == "standard"){
        $(".standard").prop("disabled",false).css("display","block");
        $(".military").prop("disabled",true).css("display","none");
    }
}
```

This seems hacky, if anyone else has a cleaner solution I will accept it as an answer.